# How to read regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code, I know what it does, but I want to understand how.

```
var color = "rgb(0, 1, 2)";
var digits = /rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);
```

can anyone please explain?

Comment: it shouldn't work (spaces!)

Comment: What do you mean with "how" if you understand what it does...? Do you want to know how regular expressions are implemented ... ? Also, it won't match the string, since the regexp has a space between the comma's, and the string doesn't.

Comment: man, read a tutorial. it will do more good than reading a specific answer for a specific example. http://www.night-ray.com/regex.pdf

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/bV5yP3/1

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/43 check the right side for explantions

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the spaces (i wrote it instead of copy-paste). as to reading a tutorial: i will, but only after I'll get some specific explanation (that's my way to learn, rev' eng').

Comment: @Carpetsmoker i undertand what it takes and what it returns, but i want to understand the regex itself. broken to the smallest parts.

Comment: copy-pasting is *good* practice. adding error-prone tasks to the process is *bad* practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/`:

`rgb` - string
`\(` - symbol `(`
`()` - group
`\d` - digit
`\d+` - at least one digit symbol
`,` - string
`\)` - symbol `)`

Comment: "at least one" - it's the plus sign? (and more than one? or specific count? or max?)
@belykh Thanks!

Comment: I thought you like rev' eng'. check the pdf.